# Can we set a custom value for the producer configuration 'delivery.timeout.ms'?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm using apache kafka clients 2.0.1 and I'm looking at the class `ProducerConfig` and didn't find the property `delivery.timeout.ms`. Does it mean, we can't override this producer configuration to set a custom value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This parameter was introduced via [KIP-91](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-91+Provide+Intuitive+User+Timeouts+in+The+Producer).

That KIP was implemented in Kafka [version 2.1.0](https://kafka.apache.org/downloads.html#2.1.0).

> Released Nov 20, 2018
>
> Kafka 2.1.0 includes a number of significant new features. Here is a
>   summary of some notable changes:
>
> - Java 11 support
> - Support for Zstandard, which achieves compression    comparable to gzip with higher compression and especially    decompression speeds
>     (KIP-110)
> - Avoid expiring committed offsets for    active consumer group (KIP-211)
> - **Provide Intuitive User Timeouts in    The Producer (KIP-91)**
> - ...

Time to upgrade :)

Comment: Thanks for the response @mazaneicha